# Rにてtidyverseが読み込めません

Tags: r, tidyverse

version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
system   x86_64, mingw32
ui       RStudio
rstudio  2022.07.2+576 Spotted Wakerobin (desktop)

以上の条件下で実行したいと思ってますが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。
解決案をアドバイスいただけると幸いです。

```
> require(tidyverse)
 要求されたパッケージ tidyverse をロード中です 
-- Attaching packages -------------- tidyverse 1.3.0 --
v ggplot2 3.4.0      v purrr   1.0.0 
v tibble  3.1.8      v dplyr   1.0.10
v tidyr   1.0.2      v stringr 1.5.0 
v readr   1.3.1      v forcats 0.5.0 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:
  .onAttach は attachNamespace()（'tidyverse' に対する）の中で失敗しました、詳細は: 
  call: NULL 
  error: `.x` must be a vector, not a function.
```

Answer (score 1):

ずいぶん古いバージョンのRをお使いのようですが、問題が無ければ最新版を試してみてはいかがでしょうか？
またRStudioをお使いでしたら`rocker/verse`のdockerコンテナを使うと環境依存の問題を大幅に減らす事が出来ます。